# Free tools for identifying Memory Leaks in .Net application

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

I am having a .Net application which when hosted in the QA server, suffers from memory leaks. What are the best free tools available, which can identify the problematic code and assist me in troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Comment: Thanks. Saw this post earlier but most of them are licensed tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, you can add any live analyzer to your codebase and determine the memory leaks.

From a simplicity perspective, I would suggest you to add CodeCracker, a live analyzer, as a nuget package. Once added, you can filter the error list with the code RuleID CC0022 - this will display all instances in your codebase where unmanaged objects have not been disposed.The light bulb feature of VS 2015, further will display you the suggestions to fix the memory leaks.